# ¿Cómo hacer con tabs/pills un menú con dos sub menús en bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Quiero hacer un menu que tenga un sub menu que, a su vez, pueda ejecutar un número. El problema ocurre cuando selecciono algo de primer sub menu, luego de segundo sub menu y luego vuelvo al primer sub menu, el resultado: me salen los dos sub menus en la misma página y no es lo que quiero.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>

li {

  padding: 10px;
  
}

</style>

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" role="tablist">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" id="first_button" data-toggle="pill" href="#first" role="tab" aria-controls="first" aria-expanded="true">Home</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" id="second_button" data-toggle="pill" href="#second" role="tab" aria-controls="second" aria-expanded="true">Profile</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="first" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="first_button">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#1" aria-controls="1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#2" aria-controls="2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#3" aria-controls="3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#4" aria-controls="4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">4</a></li>
      </ul>
       </div>
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="second" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="second_button">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#5" aria-controls="5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">5</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#6" aria-controls="6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">6</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#7" aria-controls="7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">7</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#8" aria-controls="8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">8</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-content">
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="1">1</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="2">2</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="3">3</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="4">4</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="5">5</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="6">6</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="7">7</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="8">8</div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que he hecho es dividir los contenidos del segundo tab en dos y meterlo en los tabs correspondiente ver: `<!-- AQUI CONTENIDO X -->`

Lo que pasa.. y al parecer solo con Bootstrap 4 cuando seleccionamos `Home` y elegimos un numero, luego le damos al tab `Profile` y elegimos otro numero y luego volvemos aparecen los 2 tabs de números... haz la prueba en el siguiente código:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>li{padding: 0 10px;} ul { padding: 0;}</style>

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="mi-tabs">
  
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#first" aria-controls="first">Home</a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#second" aria-controls="second">Profile</a>
  </li>
  
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="first">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#4" data-toggle="tab">4</a></li>
    </ul> 
     <!-- AQUI CONTENIDO 1 -->
    <ul class="tab-content">
      <li class="tab-pane" id="1">1</li>
      <li class="tab-pane" id="2">2</li>
      <li class="tab-pane" id="3">3</li>
      <li class="tab-pane" id="4">4</li>    
    </ul>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="second">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="#5" data-toggle="tab">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#6" data-toggle="tab">6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#7" data-toggle="tab">7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#8" data-toggle="tab">8</a></li>
    </ul>   
    <!-- AQUI CONTENIDO 2 -->
    <ul class="tab-content">      
      <li class="tab-pane" id="5">5</li>
      <li class="tab-pane" id="6">6</li>
      <li class="tab-pane" id="7">7</li>
      <li class="tab-pane" id="8">8</li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Entonces para evitar este supuestamente [bug](https://media.giphy.com/media/mq5y2jHRCAqMo/giphy.gif) he creado un pequeño *hack* para que esconda los `tabs` no activos con un poco de `jQuery` *(Más detalles en los comentarios)*:

```js
$('#mi-tabs a').on('click', function(){
  
  // Sacamos del attributo aria-control la id del tab activo
  var id_tab = $(this).attr('aria-controls'); 
  
  // Quitamos en todos los tab-pane en ¡div! la classe active
  $("div.tab-pane").removeClass('active');  
  
  // Agregamos al tab-pane correspondiente la classe active
  $('#'+id_tab).addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>li{padding: 0 10px;} ul { padding: 0;}</style>

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="mi-tabs">
  
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#first" aria-controls="first">Home</a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#second" aria-controls="second">Profile</a>
  </li>
  
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="first">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#4" data-toggle="tab">4</a></li>
    </ul> 
    
    <!-- 
    He convertido esta parte en una lista (ul) 
    para evitar cruzamientos con el código de jQuery 

    También se podría usar una classe...
    -->
    
     <!-- AQUI CONTENIDO 1 -->     
    <ul class="tab-content">
      <li class="tab-pane" id="1">1</li>
      <li class="tab-pane" id="2">2</li>
      <li class="tab-pane" id="3">3</li>
      <li class="tab-pane" id="4">4</li>    
    </ul>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="second">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="#5" data-toggle="tab">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#6" data-toggle="tab">6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#7" data-toggle="tab">7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#8" data-toggle="tab">8</a></li>
    </ul>   
    
    <!-- 
    He convertido esta parte en una lista (ul) 
    para evitar cruzamientos con el código de jQuery 

    También se podría usar una classe...
    -->
    
     <!-- AQUI CONTENIDO 2 -->
    <ul class="tab-content">      
      <li class="tab-pane" id="5">5</li>
      <li class="tab-pane" id="6">6</li>
      <li class="tab-pane" id="7">7</li>
      <li class="tab-pane" id="8">8</li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Nota aparte: He reducido el código `HTML` (quitando atributos) para que sea más visible

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que quedan habilitados los submenus al momento de dar click en cada uno de los menús. Lo único que he hecho es un pequeño script que remueve la clase 'active' (qué es la que los muestra), al momento de dar clic en un menu u otro.

OJO: Creo que la estructura de tu HTML no es la más adecuada, como dice nuestro compañero Aldanux, lo más correcto sería que implementarás clases y separaras que submenus le pertenece a que menu.

Saludos.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#first_button, #second_button').click(function(){
    $('.tab-content').children().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```html
<style>
li {
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" role="tablist">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" id="first_button" data-toggle="pill" href="#first" role="tab" aria-controls="first" aria-expanded="true">Home</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" id="second_button" data-toggle="pill" href="#second" role="tab" aria-controls="second" aria-expanded="true">Profile</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="first" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="first_button">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#1" aria-controls="1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#2" aria-controls="2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#3" aria-controls="3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#4" aria-controls="4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">4</a></li>
      </ul>
       </div>
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="second" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="second_button">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#5" aria-controls="5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">5</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#6" aria-controls="6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">6</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#7" aria-controls="7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">7</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#8" aria-controls="8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">8</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-content">
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="1">1</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="2">2</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="3">3</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="4">4</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="5">5</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="6">6</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="7">7</div>
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="8">8</div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hola Hoose... esta bien la respuesta pero hay un pequeño problema es que no se queda _memorizado_ la selección del segundo tab.. ósea los numeros